Dataform unexpected property "tags" in declaration config
I am declaring a Dataform source per the docs. The one change I am making is to add an execution tag to the config block. However I am receiving an error and I'm not sure why.
My .sqlx file
config {
    type: "declaration",
    schema: "salesforce",
    name: "contact",
    tags: ["source"],
    description: "Raw salesforce table"
}

The error: Unexpected property "tags" in declaration config. Supported properties are: ["columns","database","description","name","schema","type"]

Per the docs, you cannot add tags to a type: "declaration", only to types of table, view, incremental, assertion, or operations. The error you are receiving is correctly listing all allowed options for the IDeclarationConfig type.

I see - thank you! I was following an example project I found linked here but realize that repo is using outdated syntax.
